# Função em JavaScript acionada após clicar em div e salvar dados no banco

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysqli

Queria saber se tem como colocar um função javascript depois de clicar e arrastar uma div (melhor ainda: após "soltar" a div). Pretendo fazer um código para que cada vez que mova a div para uma tabela aconteça um UPDATE (mas nem imagino como fazer).

```
<div class="drag-container">
<ul class="drag-list">
    <li class="drag-column drag-column-on-hold">
        <span class="drag-column-header">
            <h2>Fazer</h2>

        </span>

        <div class="drag-options" id="options1"></div>

        <ul class="drag-inner-list" id="1">

            <li class="drag-item"><a href="" >

  Je    </a></li><br>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="drag-column drag-column-in-progress">
        <span class="drag-column-header">
            <h2>Fazendo</h2>

        </span>
        <div class="drag-options" id="options2"></div>
        <ul class="drag-inner-list" id="2">
            <li class="drag-item"></li>
            <li class="drag-item"></li>
            <li class="drag-item"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="drag-column drag-column-approved">
        <span class="drag-column-header">
            <h2>Feito</h2>

        </span>
        <div class="drag-options" id="options4"></div>
        <ul class="drag-inner-list" id="4">
            <li class="drag-item"></li>
            <li class="drag-item"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>

<script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/45226/dragula.min.js'></script>

<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
```

JS

```
 dragula([
document.getElementById('1'),
document.getElementById('2'),
document.getElementById('3'),
document.getElementById('4'),
document.getElementById('5')
])

.on('drag', function(el) {

// add 'is-moving' 
el.classList.add('is-moving');
})
.on('dragend', function(el) {

// remove 'is-moving'
el.classList.remove('is-moving');

// add 'is-moved' class por 600ms 
window.setTimeout(function() {
    el.classList.add('is-moved');
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        el.classList.remove('is-moved');
    }, 600);
}, 100);
});


 var createOptions = (function() {
var dragOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.drag-options');
```

P.S: ainda não terminei a programação php e html dessa página (para ficar mais bonita e funcional)

Comment: Acho que vc deveria fazer uma pergunta concisa, tipo, só como exemplo: "eu tenho 2 divs, uma ao lado da outra. Quero arrastar a da esquerda e solta-la na da direita. Como faço pra detectar que a div que arrastei foi solta na div da direita e enviar uma informação (informe que informação vc quer enviar) ao banco de dados?"... e mostre o código relevante disso tudo, de forma que as pessoas possam reproduzir a parte do HTML e do javascript.

Comment: A parte do PHP não importa nesse caso, porque aí vc faz da informação enviada como quiser, é outro departamento.

Comment: Eu copiei seu código e me mostra isso no navegador: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGyFL.jpg

Comment: pra vc ver que é complicado, o que eu tenho que fazer com isso?

Comment: Consegui ver aqui o que vc quer arrastar. É só chamar dentro da função `.on('dragend',` o que vc quer fazer.

Comment: Opa! Então, dentro da função `.on('dragend', function(el) {` vc colocar qualquer função que queira chamar depois que um elemento foi arrastado.

Comment: Qual informação vc quer enviar pro banco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Enviando o `id` da tabela para onde o elemento foi arrastado e o texto do elemento, via Ajax**

Inclua uma função Ajax dentro da função que detecta quando o elemento é arrastado e solto:

```
.on('dragend', function(el) {
   var valor_id = $(el).closest('ul').attr('id');
   var texto = $(el).text().trim();
   $.ajax({
      url: 'processa.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {dado: valor_id, texto: texto},
      success: function(result) {
           console.log(result); // aqui eu exibo no console o resultado do Ajax
       }
   });
});
```

Onde `valor_id` é a `id` da tabela pra onde o elemento foi arrastado.

`processa.php` é a página em PHP para onde será enviada a `id` pela variável `dado`.

Na página PHP, você pega o valor enviado em `dado` utilizando o código:

```
<?php
$dado = $_POST['dado'];
?>
```

Com essa informação capturada na página PHP, você a utiliza para enviar ao banco de dados, seja para fazer INSERT ou UPDATE.

O código JavaScript/jQuery ficaria assim:

```
dragula([
   document.getElementById('1'),
   document.getElementById('2'),
   document.getElementById('3'),
   document.getElementById('4'),
   document.getElementById('5')
])
.on('drag', function(el) {

   // add 'is-moving' 
   el.classList.add('is-moving');
})
.on('dragend', function(el) {

   var valor_id = $(el).closest('ul').attr('id');
   var texto = $(el).text().trim();
   $.ajax({
      url: 'processa.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {dado: valor_id, texto: texto},
      success: function(result) {
         console.log(result);
      }
   });

   // remove 'is-moving'
   el.classList.remove('is-moving');

   // add 'is-moved' class por 600ms 
   window.setTimeout(function() {
      el.classList.add('is-moved');
      window.setTimeout(function() {
         el.classList.remove('is-moved');
      }, 600);
   }, 100);
});

var createOptions = (function() {
   var dragOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.drag-options');
});
```

Comment: @J.Jones Atualizei a resposta e coloquei no Ajax a captura do texto da div.

Comment: @J.Jones Realmente não sei que erro seja este. Isso apareceu depois que colocou o meu código do Ajax?

Comment: @J.Jones Então é outra coisa do seu código.